# RAM upgrade for Lenovo Ideapad 100-14 not showing new amount

Tags: memory, upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I upgraded the RAM for the Lenovo Ideapad 100-14 from 2GB to 4GB.  But when I start the laptop, it still shows having only 2GB in the settings. The laptop its totally new. I brought the ram from the same store and they told me that it is supported.

Comment: Are you sure its fully seated in the slot?

Comment: also check what does the bios show.

Comment: What happens if you take the existing RAM out and insert the new RAM in the existing slot?

Comment: What is the maximum amount of memory supported by your device?

Comment: Is the new ram compatible?

Comment: Cruical says 8GB of DDR3. I was curious so I looked it up.

Comment: the laptop its totally new, i brought the ram from thesame store and they told me that its supported

Comment: i don't know if the laptop recognise automatic the new ram or i have to do something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question doesn't contain enough information to diagnose the problem, and a self answer says the problem no longer exists (with no information on a solution).  This appears to have been a hiccup, so of no use to anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

Its OK now, my laptop was able to read the 4GB ram.